# SQL Select with Inner Join

Tags: sql, inner-join

I know that this question has been asked before but I am finding it difficult to apply the principle to sort out my issue. I have 2 tables that I want to select data from.

I have tried using the inner join sql query below:

```
$query1 = "SELECT `entries.id`, `code_id`, FROM `entries` INNER JOIN `codes` ON `code_id` = `codes.id`";
$result = mysql_query($query1);
```

And My display is as follows:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['msisdn'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['created'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['code_id']  . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
```

I am trying to get the actual code from the table codes, and display it to a website, but I keep getting the id(number) instead of actual code.

Can someone please assist. I have checked around the internet and even got some ebooks, but I am still a newbie and would like someone to guide me through the process. All input appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're getting and what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the fields a new name if there are fields with the same name in different tables like "id":

```
$query1 = "SELECT `entries.id` as entriesid, entries.name, entries.msisdn, entries.created, `codes.id` as codesid, FROM `entries` INNER JOIN `codes` ON `entries.id` = `codes.id`";
$result = mysql_query($query1);
```

...

```
  echo "<td>" . $row['entriesid'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['msisdn'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['created'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['codesid']  . "</td>";
```

Comment: It is `code_id`, not `codes.id`, which, presumably, wouldn't require column aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select entries.* , codes.* from entries,codes where entries.code_id=codes.id");
 while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
   // Do Your Display
}
```

Hope this helps . Also mysql functions are degrading. So change that to mysqli / PDO

Comment: Thank you for the swift response guys. I am now going to try your suggestions.

Comment: Since both entries and codes has `ID` fields, you may need aliasing.

Comment: @Dukeling: I don't think alias will be necessary here. As he is comparing the ids.

Comment: `entries.code_id = codes.id`, not `entries.id = codes.id`. Also, some APIs (not sure about PHP) will complain if there are multiple fields with the same name, regardless of whether they have the same value, so it's best to avoid it.

Comment: It works for me in PHP MySQL. But I will remember your suggestion

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. No such luck. I wanted to include screenshots, but I am unable to as I am a new user. I will try with a different combination of selections.

Comment: Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in \includes\inc.invalid.php on line 76
1 Result(s) Found


    Notice: Undefined variable: sql in \includes\inc.invalid.php on line 202

    Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in \includes\inc.invalid.php on line 202

Comment: I used both suggestions, and I didnt get the desired response. Sorry for taking long to respond, minor connection issues.   // Get page data
 $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT `entries.id` as entriesid, entries.name, entries.msisdn, entries.created, `codes.id` as codesid, FROM `entries` INNER JOIN `codes` ON `entries.id` = `codes.id`");
 $result = mysql_query($query1);

Comment: First of all the code that you have put has 2 `mysql_query` going on. Then if you still have problem echo out the query and run it on a  phpmyadmin.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting my sill mistake. I was a bit upset and overlooked the obvious. @Dukeling. Thanks for your input. I managed to fix my issue. I appreciate it ten fold...